# Problem with gdal_translate when converting a GeoTiff with spherical datum to a netCDF

Tags: netcdf, gdal-translate, spherical-geometry, lambert-conformal-conic

I have a raster file with LCC projection and spherical datum. It actually has the following proj4 parameters:

```
+proj=lcc +lat_1=45 +lat_2=22 +lat_0=38.7 +lon_0=20 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6370000 +b=6370000 +units=m +no_defs
```

I use gdal as following

```
gdal_translate -unscale -of netCDF "data.tif" "data.nc"
```

The output netcdf file has the following projection

```
char lambert_conformal_conic;
  :grid_mapping_name = "lambert_conformal_conic";
  :longitude_of_central_meridian = 20.0; // double
  :false_easting = 0.0; // double
  :false_northing = 0.0; // double
  :latitude_of_projection_origin = 38.7; // double
  :standard_parallel = 45.0, 22.0; // double
  :longitude_of_prime_meridian = 0.0; // double
  :semi_major_axis = 6370000.0; // double
  :inverse_flattening = 0.0; // double
  :spatial_ref = "PROJCS[\"Lambert_Conformal_Conic\",GEOGCS[\"GCS_unnamed ellipse\",DATUM[\"unknown\",SPHEROID[\"Unknown\",6370000,0]],PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0],UNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION[\"Lambert_Conformal_Conic_2SP\"],PARAMETER[\"standard_parallel_1\",45],PARAMETER[\"standard_parallel_2\",22],PARAMETER[\"latitude_of_origin\",38.7],PARAMETER[\"central_meridian\",20],PARAMETER[\"false_easting\",0],PARAMETER[\"false_northing\",0],UNIT[\"metre\",1,AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"9001\"]]]";
  :GeoTransform = "-1088999 6000 0 927000 0 -6000 ";
```

It seems that it gets a semi_major_axis and not an earth_radius (for the spherical datums).

Do I have to define anything else in gdal_translate command?

Comment: That's fine that it's using the semi_major_axis parameter because the inverse_flattening is zero. That parameter is what determines that it's a sphere. I'd be more concerned with the fact that the other parameters aren't correct.

Comment: @mkennedy I edited my question and corrected the proj4 (I had put another proj by mistake) the other parameters are correct. thank you for the info about inverse flattening.